# Could not start jstatd on ubuntu server

Tags: rmiregistry, jstatd

I want to setup two servers with jstatd running so I can monitoring my applications on the fly. The web server have been up and running, but another server always get some exceptions like this.

> Could not bind /JStatRemoteHost to RMI Registry
>   java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
>   nested exception is:      java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error
>   unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   sun.jvmstat.monitor.remote.RemoteHost (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)    at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)   at
>   sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.bind(Jstatd.java:57)  at
>   sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:143) Caused by:
>   java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   sun.jvmstat.monitor.remote.RemoteHost (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   sun.jvmstat.monitor.remote.RemoteHost (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:554)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:263)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1556)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1512)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     ... 13 more

I am sure jstatd loaded the policy file which content is

> grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {    permission
>   java.security.AllPermission; };

I cannot figure whats the problem come from, please help.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you.

As far as I understood the exception occurred on the **rmi registry** side because it couldn't find the class **sun.jvmstat.monitor.remote.RemoteHost** located inside **tools.jar**.

In my case the solution was to specify the **java.rmi.server.codebase** property when starting **rmiregistry**. After specifying the codebase property the problem gone.
Please try to start the **rmiregistry** using the following command for Linux/Solaris:

> rmiregistry
>   -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar &

or for Windows (though I didn't test it fully)

> start rmiregistry
>   -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase="%JAVA_HOME%/../lib/tools.jar"

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I'm now hitting 'Failed to start RMI naming service at 1099'